# ios swift custom uitablecell how to put several items (labels, images)

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I have custom cell as shown in image below :

[image: custom cell]

I want to make an indentation from leading and trailing edges, like below

[image: that]

Is it possible to do it by using autolayout?
I tried adding +5 to leading constraint with decrease Compression Resistance Priority like [image: that] but it does not work.

Comment: Add leading and trailing space constraints for the first and last components in a cell respectively. For the remaining components in a cell, add constraints based/dependent on the first and last components in a cell. Leave Compression Resistance Priority as it is.

Comment: I think I don't understand how does autolayout work, I put the Stackview's Distribution to Fill, and then added constraints like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hwdxrmvv2kijunk/how%20it%20is%20now.png?dl=0    and decrease Compression Resistance Priority for the first element  but the last element still does not have indentation : https://www.dropbox.com/s/1pds8okb18vi8rk/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202017-12-25%20%D0%B2%2017.43.05.png?dl=0

Comment: You should have a look at how actually autolayout works and then look to add desired constraints. Unless you have a clear idea of how it works, you may face more difficulties going ahead. So have a look at some tutorials on autolayout and I am sure you will be a pro once you clear the concept.

Answer (score 0):

So you need padding of 5 pt on the left ? Yes, you can do it with auto-layout. You may remove the constraint you marked in the image, and instead add another leading constraint form the stack view to the cell content view.

Another option would be to **add a** dummy view (or even better, a **UILayoutGuide**) with width as 5 pt, right to the left of this day label.

Comment: I think I don't understand how does autolayout work, I put the Stackview's Distribution to Fill, and then added constraints like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hwdxrmvv2kijunk/how%20it%20is%20now.png?dl=0    and decrease Compression Resistance Priority for the first element  but the last element still does not have indentation : https://www.dropbox.com/s/1pds8okb18vi8rk/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202017-12-25%20%D0%B2%2017.43.05.png?dl=0

Comment: Well, I think you don't need to use the stack view. Just add the elements directly to the cell content view, and it should work well.

Comment: I tried it also, but in this case I can not set lead/trail constrats between elements, constraits apply only to view in which they are.

Comment: Of-course you can. Just tap control key, and DRAG from source element to the destination element, and in the popover, select the appropriate constraint you want to add.

Comment: I tried manually trough ctrl+DRAG but it does not make it correct. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gtnq9fxsehy0mc/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202017-12-25%20%D0%B2%2019.03.46.png?dl=0  and result is:             https://www.dropbox.com/s/t1i41a93mo0v9qc/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202017-12-25%20%D0%B2%2019.04.01.png?dl=0 (I mean I can not add it from Add new constrait button, where is autolayout suggest edges)